# Unwrapping optional inside map closure in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an instance of `Friend` while using `map` on `myEmplyee` array. Its crashing because I am forced unwrapping `.imageString` property.

**What I want is:**
If the `imageString` in `Employee` is `nil` then I want `imageUrl` property to also be `nil` when the instance of `Friend` is created.

*Pasting my code below:*

```
import UIKit

struct Employee {
    var name: String
    var imageString: String?
}

struct Friend {
    var name: String
    var imageUrl: URL?
}

var myEmplyee = [Employee]()
myEmplyee.append(Employee(name: "a1", imageString: "a1ImageUrl.png"))
myEmplyee.append(Employee(name: "a2", imageString: "a2ImageUrl.png"))
myEmplyee.append(Employee(name: "a3", imageString: "a3ImageUrl.png"))
myEmplyee.append(Employee(name: "a4", imageString: "a4ImageUrl.png"))
myEmplyee.append(Employee(name: "a5", imageString: "a5ImageUrl.png"))
myEmplyee.append(Employee(name: "a6", imageString: nil))

var friendList = myEmplyee.map { Friend(name: $0.name, lName: URL(string: "https:" + $0.imageString!)) }

for obj in friendList {
    print("First Name: \(obj.name), Last Name: \(obj.imageUrl)" )
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Basically in my project I have ```Employee``` struct as a Model (updated from server response) and I am looping through it to create an array of another type ```Friend```. It was working fine unless one of the property of ```Employee``` because ```Optional```. I have simplified the code to test it on play ground.

Comment: What URL do you want when the last name is nil? And a URL such as `http://Smith` isn't very useful. And naming a `URL` property as `lName` is misleading as well.

Comment: Please, in the future, post your question in the proper form the first time. You have rewritten your question completely two times now. Three answers have been posted and all three have become invalid due to your changes. Please avoid wasting everyone's time by thinking through your question before posting. Thanks.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right, my apologies.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
let friendList = myEmplyee.map { employee -> Friend in
    let url = employee.imageString.flatMap { URL(string: "https:" + $0) }
    return Friend(name: employee.name, imageUrl: url)
}
```

The [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) in conjunction with optional says “if this optional is not `nil`, then return the value of this closure.”

---

Needless to say, though, just appending the image name after “https:” isn’t going to work. E.g., “https:a1ImageUrl.png” is not a valid URL. You probably want something like:

```
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/images/")!
let friendList = myEmplyee.map { employee -> Friend in
    let url = employee.imageString.map { baseURL.appendingPathComponent($0) }
    return Friend(name: employee.name, imageUrl: url)
}
```

Because `appendingPathComponent` doesn’t return an optional, in this case we can use [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) instead of `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

You changed your question, with this new requirement:

> What I want is: If the imageString in Employee is nil then I want
>   imageUrl property to also be nil when the instance of Friend is
>   created.

In this case, you can use `flatMap` on *optional* to provide the result:

```
var friendList = myEmplyee.map { Friend(name: $0.name,
    imageUrl: $0.imageString.flatMap { imgStr in URL(string: "https:" + imgStr) } ) }
```

Comment: There is no `lName` property any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *unwrap* `imageString` if exists using ***optional binding*** (**`if let`**) and then create the `URL` instance using the *unwrapped value*, i.e.

```
let friendList = myEmplyee.map { (emp) -> Friend in
    var url: URL?
    if let imageString = emp.imageString {
        url = URL(string: "https:" + imageString)
    }
    return Friend(name: emp.name, imageUrl: url)
}
```